# How to update data into a specific column in a sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table containing the name, score 1, score 2, and score 3 of a player. There are multiple data entries and I would like to know how to add the player's score to their correct column, i.e.:

```
Name, Score 1, Score 2, Score 3
John,      12,    ____,    ____
```

How would I specify what column to insert the player's score 2 into when using

```
.execute('''INSERT INTO ScoresTable (name, score 1, score 2, score 3)''')
```

Do I use the column index but how would I implement that into the code?

Answer (score 6):

To alter existing rows, you need to use an [`UPDATE` statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html), with a `WHERE` filter:

```
UPDATE ScoresTable SET ("score 1"=12, "score 2"=20, "score 3"=42) WHERE name='John'
```

I used `".."` double quoting around the column names since they have spaces in them.

Using a cursor in Python, with SQL parameters, that'd translate to:

```
cursor.execute('''\
    UPDATE ScoresTable SET ("score 1"=?, "score 2"=?, "score 3"=?)
    WHERE name=?
    ''', (score1, score2, score3, name))
```